# How to position out.println() when outputting from java servlet?

Tags: java, html, css, servlets

[image]

Hi everyone, please have a look at the screen design link above.At the top you can see it says "Employee Not Found!" This is deliberately done, and is the result of entering an employee ID which is not found, as shown in the servlet below. However, I was wondering how can I position this? Or is there an easier way of outputting feedback to the user? As you can see, the message is ruining my CSS by being displayed at the top. Is there a better way of outputting this message? or maybe positioning the out.println?

ViewEmployeeInfo.java:

```
out.println("Employee Not Found!"); 
                     RequestDispatcher qs = request.getRequestDispatcher("ViewEmployee.html"); 
                     qs.include(request, response);
```

ViewEmployee.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta charset = "UTF-8"> 
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "main.css">
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "sidebar.css">
<title>Update Employee Information</title>
<style>
table { border-collapse: collapse; width: 50%; } th, td { text-align: left; padding: 8px; } tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
tr:hover {background-color: #e2f4ff;}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<ul>
<li><a  href="PersonalInfoOutput">View Personal Information</a></li>
<li><a  href="ExpenseClaim.html">View Expense Claims</a></li>
<li><a  href=asdasd>View Payslips</a></li>
<li><a  href="changePassAdmin.html" >Change Password</a></li>
<li><a  href ="manageEmployee.html" class=active>Maintain Employee Information</a></li>
<li><a  href=asdasdasd>Maintain Tax Information</a></li>
<li><a  href=asdasd>Maintain Payroll Items</a></li>
<li><a  href="TimeSheet.html">Maintain Timesheet</a></li>
<li><a  href="EmployeeExpense.html">Maintain Employee Expenses</a></li>
<li><a  href=asda>Run Payroll</a></li>
<li><a  href=asdasds>Generate Reports</a></li>

</ul>

<div style=margin-left:25%;padding:1px;>
</div>

<div id="container">
<h1>View Employee Information</h1>
<form action ="ViewEmployeeInfo" method = "post"> 

    <table border ="1"> 

    <tr>
    <td>Employee ID Search:</td>
    <td><input type = "search" name = "employee_id"  pattern="[0-9]{4}" title="4 digit number: e.g. 1234" maxlength="4" required>   <input type ="submit" value="Search"> 
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: why are you even using servlets to write html

Comment: @Ramanlfc html is for displaying the page. I'm using servlet to communicate with database to see if employee exists or not.

Comment: So how do you intend to display the next page, when you show information from the database? Using JSP, or Thymeleaf, or FreeMarker, or...? Any page with dynamic content should be built using a template with one of those technologies. The "Employee Not Found!" message is dynamic content, so this page should be built using a template too.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify with CSS by adding  tag in

```
out.println("<div id="info">Employee Not Found!</div>");
```

Comment: You're missing the point, that the `println` output is written to the response *before* the html content is added, so the text appears before `<!DOCTYPE html>`, and that is so very very wrong.

Comment: @Andreas >> Is there more need <!DOCTYPE html> in java  class ? Because I saw <!DOCTYPE html> in ViewEmployee.html.

Comment: Java code has (abbreviated) `println("Employee Not Found!"); include("ViewEmployee.html");`, so the message is written before the html content that starts with `<!DOCTYPE html>`, so result is: `Employee Not Found!<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>...`. *That* is what the browser will see. With your code, the `<div>` will occur before `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<html>` and `<head>`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Use following `out` statement

```
out.println("<span class='messageBox'>Employee Not Found!</span>");
```

Add css style inside `<style>...</style>` in `head` tag using class `messageBox` like below:

```
.messageBox {
    color: red;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 22px; 
}
```

Change css as your requirement.!!!

Comment: You're missing the point, that the `println` output is written to the response *before* the html content is added, so the text appears before `<!DOCTYPE html>`, and that is so very very wrong.